# Looking for a Kinect tutorial

Tags: c#, kinect

Does anyone have a good tutorial or information how can I start programming C# application using Kinect? I have been searching and all I find are videos but no real articles.

Comment: +1 A question that I was going to ask. I'm hoping to write a Kinect program for my final University project.  Not sure what exactly yet.  Think i'll wait until the MS API comes out and then see what can be done.

Comment: Coding4Fun has pretty straightforward demos (some with source code) that works with the SDK. Hope it helps. Here's the link: [Coding4Fun](https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect?page=3) This provides a good walk through [The-Busy-Developers-Guide-to-the-Kinect-SDK-Beta](https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/The-Busy-Developers-Guide-to-the-Kinect-SDK-Beta) and don't forget to get the [Coding4Fun Kinect Toolkit](https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Coding4Fun-Kinect-Toolkit)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've seen several people talk about starting from http://codelaboratories.com/nui

Their platform comes with a "WPF/C# (.NET 3.5) Visual Studio 2010 Sample Application" - and there's lots of talk on forums like http://nuigroup.com/forums/viewthread/11249/ - plus look on here under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kinect

Whatever you write, bear in mind that the official SDK is on the way - my guess is that there might be some sort of CTP available near MIX11?

You're definitely in pioneer territory - so expect to hit the odd problem along the way - but enjoy it!

---

Update - the official SDK will be available here - http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/kinectsdk/ - "soon"

Answer (score 3):

I advise to take a look at [OpenNi](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect). This project (Which is was founded by PrimeSence, the company behind Kinect's technology) provides "middleware" for skeleton tracking, as well as gesture recognition. 
The middleware supports all PrimeSence's based products (as well as any other that will follow the open standard) such as ASUS's Xtion Pro (which is cheaper than the Kinect, but lacks the video camera).

It comes with C# and Unity wrappers.

You may find the specific drivers for Kinect [here](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect), and a discussion group [here](http://groups.google.com/group/openni-dev).

Good Luck!